# What causes this unintentional infinite loops in my code in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.5

What is the cause of unintentional infinite loops in my code in Python 2.7 but in Python 3.5 gives me error message?

Python 3.5 gives `TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()`, How should I resolve it?

### Program

```
condition = '2'

while condition > 5:

    print 'test'
```

Comment: You're not modifying your `condition`

Comment: In Python 3.5, it would also fail because `print` does not include parentheses.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to compare `'2'` (a [`string`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/string.html)) to `5` (an [`int`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex)). You should declare without quotes:

```
condition = 2
```

Comment: [See also](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3270680)